# I'm trying to read ADC value which is for temperature, and send by UART if it reached to very hot condition

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

So I can read the ADC value for temperature and also I send a String when it reached too hot value. But my problem is; it sends the string a lot of times. I'm trying to send just once. I tried to fix it by using delay but it's not working good enough.

```
    if ( LM35_ADC_Value == 580 )
        {   
           USART_puts(USART2,"VERY_HOT\n");
           delay(1680000000000);
                                                                                 
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your implementation from a stateless model to a stateful model. For example, store the previous `LM35_ADC_Value`, and print the string only if it went up to 580 from a previously lower value.

Comment: It's seems pretty unlikely that `delay` is accepting a `uint64_t`, so maybe start by double-checking your compiler warnings.

Comment: Also, how do you filter the ADC reads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement a state with possibly a hysteresis, something like this:

```
   bool veryhotsent = false;

   ...

   if ( veryhotsent )
   {
     if ( LM35_ADC_Value < 578 )        // change that value to whatever is suitable
        veryhotsent = false;            // for your application
   }
   else if ( LM35_ADC_Value >= 580 )    // use >=, otherwise you might miss the raise
   {   
      USART_puts(USART2,"VERY_HOT\n");
      veryhotsent = true;
   }
```

- As soon as the temperature raises above 580, you send the message.
- The messagee won't be resent unless the temperature lowers to 578 and raises to more than 580 again.

Also it is very important to use `>= 580` instead of `== 580`, otherwise no message will be sent if the temperature raises from say 579 to 581 between two mesures, which can be absolutely fatal depending on your application.